# Can you remove drill through filter from measures in Power BI?

Tags: dax, measure, drillthrough

I am trying to use the drill through filter to take my user to other data related to that date. Essentially I have an overview page and I want the user to click on a date and drill through to the next page, where it will show them test scores nearest to that date.

I think I need to do two things 1) store the filter date as a variable so I can use it to find the nearest test date to the filtered date 2) create measures which ignore the filtered drill through date and can for example calculate the minimum or maximum test scores on all the tests overall.

I'm not sure if either of these options are possible but any help is greatly appreciated. TIA